# Parsing JSON - Can't get boolean value from JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been trying to figure out how to do some basic stuff in Java..

I've got a request being made to an API, which returns the following JSON.

```
{"success": false, "message": "some string", "data": []}
```

This is represented by the String `result` in the following:

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject();
success = root.getAsJsonObject("success").getAsBoolean();
```

I need to get the "success" parameter as a boolean. Getting an error on the `getAsBoolean()` call.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be
>   cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the bool value of "success"?

Comment: try something like gson.fromJson("false", Boolean.class);

Comment: change it to `getAsJsonPrimitive` as success is not a JsonObject?

Comment: which version are you using???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that is breaking your code is that you are calling the wrong method...

Do

```
success = root.get("success").getAsBoolean();
```

instead of

```
success = root.getAsJsonObject("success").getAsBoolean();
```

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = "{\"success\": false, \"message\": \"some string\", \"data\": []}";
    JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject();
    boolean success = root.get("success").getAsBoolean();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you're calling `root.getAsJsonObject("success")` while the `success` is a boolean value itself, not an object.

Try following

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject();
success = root.get("success").getAsBoolean();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the root.get("success") method. Success isn't really a json object, it's a member of a json object. See here https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#get-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

If root is a jsonObject

```
root.getBoolean("success");
```